# Not able to display nested class values in lightning component

Tags: apex, lightning

I am not able to display the iteration details for the third time 
this is my component class:

```
<table class="slds-table slds-table_bordered slds-table_cell-buffer slds-table_striped">
.......
<tbody>
     <aura:iteration items="{!v.ResponseObj.customers}" var="cus">
     <tr>
        <th scope="row">
           <div class="slds-truncate" title="{!cus.line_of_business}">{!cus.line_of_business}</div>
        </th>
        <aura:iteration items="{!cus.contacts}" var="cus1">
        <th scope="row">
            <div class="slds-truncate" title="{!cus1.name}">{!cus1.name}</div>
        </th>
        <th scope="row">
            <div class="slds-truncate" title="{!cus1.home_phone}{!cus1.home_phone}</div>
        </th>
        <th scope="row">
            <div class="slds-truncate" title="{!cus1.email}">{!cus1.email}</div>
        </th>
        <aura:iteration items="{!cus1.address}" var="cus2">
        <th scope="row">
            <div class="slds-truncate" >{!cus2.street}</div>
        </th>
       </aura:iteration>
      </aura:iteration>
     </tr>
  </aura:iteration>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

the 3rd iteration loop with the "address" is not displayed 
and this is my nested class:

```
public class JSON2Apex{
    public String request_tracking_id;  //12
    @AuraEnabled public cls_customers[] customers {get;set;}
    public cls_metadata metadata;
    public class cls_customers {
        public String id    {get;set;}//000131417543005
        public String status {get;set;} //CANCELLED
        public String category {get;set;}   //OPEN MARKET
        @AuraEnabled public String line_of_business {get;set;}  //COMMERCIAL
        public String account_type {get;set;}   //master
        public String is_national_account;  //False
        public String is_central_billed;    //False
        @AuraEnabled public cls_contacts[] contacts {get;set;}
        @AuraEnabled public cls_wm_metadata wm_metadata {get;set;} 
    }
    public class cls_contacts {
        public String type {get;set;}   //service
        public String organization_name {get;set;}  //SAWRIDGE HOTEL
        @AuraEnabled public String name {get;set;}  //VIPUL
        @AuraEnabled public String home_phone {get;set;}    //7807997417
        @AuraEnabled public String email {get;set;} //tboutilier@sawridge.com
        public String fax {get;set;}    //7804283335
        @AuraEnabled public cls_address address {get;set;}
        public cls_cleansed_address cleansed_address;
    }
    public class cls_address {
        @AuraEnabled public String street {get;set;}    //530 MACKENZIE BLVD
        @AuraEnabled public String street2 {get;set;}   //VIPUL
        @AuraEnabled public String city {get;set;}  //FORT MCMURRAY
        @AuraEnabled public String state {get;set;} //AB
        @AuraEnabled public String postal_code {get;set;}   //T9H 4C8
        @AuraEnabled public String country {get;set;}   //CA
    }
    public class cls_cleansed_address {
        public String street;   //530 MACKENZIE BLVD
        public String street2;  //VIPUL
        public String city; //FORT MCMURRAY
        public String state;    //AB
        public String postal_code;  //T9H 4C8- 
        public String country;  //CA
    }
    public class cls_wm_metadata{
        public String library;  //202A
        public String company_code; //949
        public String mas_account_number;   //949-663
        public String mas_status;   //WRTOFFCAN
        public String business_unit;    //B00269
        public String is_canadian_billed;   //True
    }
    public class cls_metadata {
        public String totalCount;   //1
    }
    public static JSON2Apex parse(String json){
        return (JSON2Apex) System.JSON.deserialize(json, JSON2Apex.class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your wrapper, you have `cls_customers` and each `cls_customers` has list of `cls_contacts` and field name is `contacts` and every `cls_contacts` has another field as `address` of type `cls_address`
So, to display the address information, you don't need to use aura:iteration as it is not list of `cls_address`.

Instead, use the fields directly

```
<aura:iteration items="{!cus.contacts}" var="cus1">
    <th scope="row">
        <div class="slds-truncate" title="{!cus1.name}">{!cus1.name}</div>
    </th>
    <th scope="row">
        <div class="slds-truncate" title="{!cus1.home_phone}{!cus1.home_phone}</div>
    </th>
    <th scope="row">
        <div class="slds-truncate" title="{!cus1.email}">{!cus1.email}</div>
    </th>
    {!cus1.address.street} {!cus1.address.state} {!cus1.address.country}
</aura:iteration>
```